# Dart takes too much RAM while generating random numbers and appending them into a file

Tags: dart, file-io, dart-io

I am doing a project that involves generating 1 billion random 0/1 numbers and storing them in a file. This is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

final int COUNT = 1000000000;
final Random randomizer = new Random();
final File file = new File('./dart/dart.txt');

void main() {
  if (file.existsSync()) {
    file.deleteSync();
  }
  file.createSync();
  
  DateTime before = new DateTime.now();
  IOSink sink = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.append);

  for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
    sink.write(nextNumber().toString());
  }
  sink.close();

  DateTime after = new DateTime.now();
  print(after.millisecondsSinceEpoch - before.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
}

int nextNumber() {
  return randomizer.nextInt(2);
}
```

It works fine with `COUNT=10000`, taking a dozen milliseconds to generate 10000 random numbers. However, as I raise `COUNT` to 1 billion, it took about 25GB of my RAM and ran for more than 40 minutes non-stop. I had to kill the process instead of letting it continue running.

How can I fix this?

P.S. I can't change the programming language since using different programming languages to generate such numbers are one aspect of my project. I also use C++, Java, Javascript, PS, Python, etc. to generate such big data, and none of them met this problem. The final file storing the data is less than 1 GB.

Comment: Note that you're measuring the time to compute `COUNT` random numbers but not the time to write them to disk (since you neglect to do `await sink.flush(); await sink.close();` first).  Therefore the apparent time taken isn't going to scale as expected.  I also suspect that `IOSink` does not automatically flush its buffer when it gets too full, so you'll end up buffering all `COUNT` values.  You perhaps should call `await sink.flush();` periodically (e.g. every 10000 iterations), which hopefully should fix the RAM usage (and maybe help with the duration too if the RAM usage caused paging).

Comment: I realized that it's not that `IOSink` doesn't flush its buffer automatically (and you can observe that `dart.txt` does grow without explicit flushing), it's that without an occasional `await sink.flush();`, your loop is generating data *much* faster than it can be written to disk, so `IOSink` ends up buffering almost all of it.